# What is the standard location of piano pedals?

Tags: piano, keyboard-pedals

My digital piano has a separate pedal block that can be placed at any distance from the keyboard. However I think makes a lot of sense to position it in a standard way, how it is typically positioned. As it tends to slide, I am now screwing it to the floor and need to know the recommended location.

What is a typical standard distance of the piano pedal block, measured from the front of the white keys to the tip, or root, of the pedals?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a standard for that. Every piano I've seen has a different key height, pedal position and sensitivity. Especially upright pianos suffer from some physical limitations. Also they need to fit players of every size. That's why many piano pedals are actually L shaped. It usually takes some time to get used to playing a piano for the first time.

Since digital piano pedals are not L shaped it is better to align with your foot to the most comfortable position and do not copy real piano measures directly. As a general measure, you should adjust it to your own standing position. It should be comfy to reach with a little effort without extending for it, but also shouldn't bother your foot while not in use. Sustain pedals are positioned a little right from the center. You can place it aligned with your right foot (or toe) in your standard position, a few centimeters ahead. Do also a Google Image search for "piano position".

[image]

Ah, also before screwing it to the floor, use double side tapes and play for a while and ensure the position is comfortable. There is no such standard, it is better that you play comfortably.

*NOTE: I couldn't get the Preformatted text to work. Adding a crappy screenshot instead.*

Answer (score 1):

Before making holes in the floor, attach a strip of carpet or similar to the underside of the pedal, long enough for your foot to rest on the carpet while the pedal is in a comfy position. Your foot will keep it from sliding away. Where it goes is more important for your comfort than to be in a standard position, and there's no industry standard.